# How to convert date (1991-08-23T00:00:00) which is captured in response and then convert this format (08-23-1991) in vugen?

Tags: scripting, loadrunner, vugen

I am working on a script where I need to submit a form and do some authentication during the steps. I am using LoadRunner Vugen for scripting. For one of the request's response I can see birthdate is coming like below:
"suffixName": ""
"birthDate": "1991-08-23T00:00:00",
"agencyName": ""

In another later request I can see in jason body the same date is used like below

"Body={\agentSuffix":null,"agentFirstName":"XYZ","agentLastName":"WSD","agentBirthDate":"08-23-1991" and so on with additional body.

I am able to capture the date from response by using web_reg_save_param_ex. But now how do I convert the value so that I can use it in next jason body in a custom request. I just need help to capture it.

Captured value: 1991-08-23T00:00:00
Expected value: 08/23/1991

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

1. Correlate for the string
2. Use your programming skills in the language of your virtual user to transform transform the string into a new string.  Your test code might be C, JavaScript, Java, ... so use language-appropriate string conversion functions.

Hints

- "LB=birthDate":"", "RB=T00:00:00"
- Conside the loop and what this means for the use of substring and sprintf();

  for (counter=0;counter<=strlen(lr_eval_string(***MyCorrelatedVarName***));counter++)

  { lr_message("%s",&lr_eval_string(***MyCorrelatedVarName***)[counter]); }